# webpack re-useable modules with separate entry points?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I am slightly confused by the best way to make use of webpack when you are consuming the output as a `library` or `module`, so for example let us pretend I have:

- some-model.js
- some-logic.js (consumes some-model)

then I want to re-use the above in several separate projects, so I have compiled the above into a bundle fine, so I now have `some-bundle.js` and I want to basically be able to do in the browser:

`var someLogic = new SomeLogic();`

I am aware that if I was able to do the above it would look more like `var SomeLogic = new SomeBundle.SomeLogic();` as I would probably need to export some central var to wrap the underlying components.

Now from what I can tell webpack does not expose anything, its all just self executing and will run whatever entry point you pass in, however in this instance I do not have an entry point as its just a re-useable module (in reality this may end up also containing templates, css, images etc).

So I am sure there is a simple thing I am missing here but how do I go about consuming this webpack output and be able to consume the logic inside the bundle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After talking in the gitter channel it seems what I want here is:

https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#output-librarytarget

This allows me to specify a library name and how to export it, this way I can use the content inside the webpack module as if it was a module entry point.